# Multiple AppDomain's - What domain "AppDomain.CurrentDomain" return?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, assemblies, .net-assembly

If we call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` inside codes loaded into separate domains, what domain reference we'll get ? The main domain reference or the domain reference where the current code is loaded ?

Suppose, we're loading assemblies inside a domain, and we need to probe assemblies in the event `AssemblyResolve`: We can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` to get the current domain reference or we'll need to create a way to pass the domain reference to it ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, i think it depends which AppDomain you call the AppDomain.CurrentDomain property in, i.e. it returns the AppDomain that the DLL is running in. However AppDomain.CurrentDomain returns an AppDomain object, and you need to keep track of your domains anyway so you can unload them.  If you look at the example code just do what you need to do against which ever AppDomain object you need to.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx

Comment: @BenRobinson: The need to keep track is ok. But in certain situations is more convenient to just use a static accessor, instead of pollute the code with workarounds, like current thread, current process, current session, and so on.

Comment: Static is per domain so if you call a static property that itself calls AppDomain.CurrentDomain then it will return the same thing as calling it directly.  So i think however you called AppDomain.CurrentDomain inside the AssemblyResolve event handler it would return the host AppDomain because that is where the event handler is running.  Have you tried it to see what happens.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Maybe the context returned isn't really a static field. A static getter may returns a contextual version automatically, look the answer from Hans Passant.

Comment: True enough, to be honest my experience with using AppDomains explicitly is fairly minimal, hence the comments rather than me posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain returns the domain in which your code is running.  Yes, using it in an AssemblyResolve event handler is always safe and correct.  That event is specific to each AppDomain and will be fired when the AppDomain needs an assembly it cannot otherwise find itself.

The event handler's `e` argument is of type ResolveEventArgs.  Which only tells you the name of the assembly, not the AppDomain that needs it.  It is assumed you already know.  Use CurrentDomain if you forgot.

Do favor using AppDomainSetup so you don't need this event handler.

Comment: I already tried so I need to ask: Could you provide me materials or samples that explains how to use AppDomainSetup to "bypass" AssemblyResolve ? In my solution I need to load in a separate domain an assembly outside my running assembly folder and it depends from assemblies located in several places, including the folder where is the .exe assembly and embedded assemblies (like resources).

Comment: My AppDomainSetup tries. I setted in `ApplicationBase` the .exe path, and in `PrivateBinPath` a list of folders on which the first is the path of the assembly to be loaded, and others folders where assemblies may be, separated by ";". When domain is created, I load into it an assembly and `Load()` works, after that I get all types from it and more assemblies are loaded, then I instantiate a class `myAssembly.CreateInstance(myType)`, so AssemlyResolve is fired to an unknown assembly "<myAssembly>.resources". What's wrong in AppDomainSetup to solve this unknown assembly (is embedded ?) ?

Comment: I can't look over your shoulder from here.  A .resources file normally contains resources and is embedded in the assembly manifest.  You should return null for assembly requests that you don't recognize.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I asked a new question about it. May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866351/loading-assemblies-with-embedded-assemblies-resources-in-isolated-appdomains